# Match the size of multiple background images

Tags: 3d-view, image

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNbAmJ3eubo) tutorial in the first couple of minutes it is explained how to set the dimensions of a cube and match the background images to this mesh. I have tried to get it right but till now I did not succeed. This is what the creator of the tutorial says in the comments:

> I'm keeping only one mesh and just changing the x and y values of my
>   background images you can see me add at 3:00. We want all the
>   background images to match that one mesh.

Here are my images:

[image]
[image]

I think front and back images match to the mesh. But for the right, left and top view I only get one dimension matching. I don't see how you can match both dimensions matching without changing the mesh

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background images are scaled to different sizes. Scale them consitently to 27.6cm.

[image]

Then just place them just changing the x and y values of the backround images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did this to match the dimensions of the mesh. As I understand it the background images must match both dimensions of the mesh ? When I scale them consistently I don't get the images matched to the mesh or do I miss something ?

Comment: make all of them the same!

Comment: I am on my way :)

Comment: I have to admit that you are right :) I am flabbergasted .... (at first instance I had all image at the same scaling )